# How to compute decadal data?

Tags: r

I have tried to have a decadal data using the mean of each ten rows, But in meteorological field it is wrong.I have thirty years of data and I would like to know how to compute the decadal data from it.

Comment: Do you have a year column? Assign your decades, `your_data$decade = 10 * (your_data$year %/% 10)` and then use your preferred method of [calculating mean by group](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/903061).

Comment: In the somewhat unlikely event it's a time series, `aggregate(JohnsonJohnson, ndeltat = 10, FUN = mean)`

Comment: yeah I have year column. What I want is the meteorological decadal. For instance what you suggest I will have 4 decadal in January while in meteorological I should have 3 decadal.